# Search an array type column in DataTables.js

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am using DataTables.js to display a table. The data source for one of the columns contains an array of data:

```
TestField: ["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"]
```

When displaying the table to the user, DataTables automatically concatenates these values with a comma and displays them as `Value 1,Value 2,Value 3`.

However, when I try to search this column, the search returns no result:

```
g_datatable.column("TestField:name").search("Value").draw(); //no results - empty table
```

What is the way to run a search on this type of column in DataTables.js?

Comment: This is an odd one and I'm unable to replicate (https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/5pg8de3x/). I can search for Tiger using "System Architect, Accountant, Junior Technical Author", "System Architect,Accountant,Junior Technical Author" or "Accountant". What versions are you using?

Comment: Updated JSFiddle, it's not your className is it?

Comment: @annoyingmouse Thanks for creating the fiddle! I am using DataTables 1.10.12

Comment: Pretty sure it's the "TestField:name" as I'm still unable to replicate, you're welcome to clone the JSFiddle and try to get the problem to replicate there? The DataTable version seems pretty modern...

Comment: @annoyingmouse I just ended up converting array to string before passing my data to the DataTable. Dumb but works.